# What is " undefined method `rails' ", and how do I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm building a simple setup of ActiveAdmin to get my feet wet with basic admin coding in RoR. Nothing fancy. I generated a "post" controller and resource and model, as shown below. My issue is that I am still getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::PostsController#index
undefined method `rails' for #<Admin::PostsController:0x00000107ad3038>
```

It's correct in that I haven't defined a `rails` method, but I also haven't called one. In fact, there's no `rails` method called anywhere in any of my code. This leads me to believe that I have a syntax issue somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. Please help me make sense of this.

---

**/admin/post.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

  scope_to :rails

  permit_params :title, :slug, :blurb, :content, :category_id

  index do
    column :title
    column :slug
    column :blurb
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  form :html => {:enctype => "multipart/form-data"} do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :slug
      f.input :blurb
      f.input :category
      f.input :content, :as => :text
    end

    f.inputs "Images" do
      f.input :image, :label => 'Post Image', :as => :file
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

---

**/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

---

**/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category
  scope :rails, -> { where(category_id: 1) }

end
```

---

As you can see, I never call any `rails` method in my code. Where is that error coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably coming from this line in your view admin/post.rb:

```
scope_to :rails
```

Try commenting that out.

Then try something like this instead:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  controller do
    def resource
      Post.where(category_id: 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Commenting out the `scope_to :rails` line worked like a charm! Why does that work? And what's the controller block you added?

Comment: well you had put in a scope to limit the posts to a category_id of 1 in your model.  I have no idea why you did that.  I just gave you code to make that work.

Comment: I guess you just copied this code from somewhere then.  So if you don't need to modify the scope, just get rid of it.

Comment: I'm working out of Andy Hawthorne's "Jump Start Rails" book, and he was creating a button on the Post's index page, which would allow the user to quickly and simply add filtering of the records shown on the index page. In this case, it was creating a button to filter by the category "Rails", which happens to be the first category in the Category table.

Comment: And NOW, I see where the `undefined method rails` issue references from. But why did the application assume `:rails` to be a method name?

Comment: Also, your alternative code block above doesn't create the button like I was trying to. But thanks to your help finding the line that was causing the error, I figured out that changing the line to simply `scope :rails` actually does what I was trying to do.